# ffmpeg lame mp3 problem

Tags: linux, installation, mp3, ffmpeg

i wanted to install ffmpeg with lame mp3 support.its procedure is as follows:

```
cd /usr/local/src/ffmpeg/
./configure –enable-libmp3lame –enable-libogg –enable-libvorbis 
make && make install
```

but i have not passed -enable-libmp3lame during installing to ./configure so mp3lame support is not available.how can i modify existing installation to install libmp3

Answer (score 1):

You can't modify it without recompile. You have to run `configure` and `make` again with correct switches.

`make install` will then overwrite current versions of your ffmpeg with correct one.

---

Disclaimer: yes, you can patch binary files, but that's not practical in any sense in this case.